# Conditions for the squared gradient norm to be convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, non-convex-optimization

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. I am looking for conditions under which the function $$x\mapsto \Vert\nabla f(x)\Vert^2$$ is convex.

It obviously hold if $f$ is quadratic, and therefore $\nabla f$ is linear. So I am wondering whether it holds for functions with Lipschitz gradients?

Comment: Euclidean norm?

Answer (score 0):

Every norm $||\cdot||$ is convex. The quadratic function $x^2$ is non-decreasing in $x\ge0$, so the squared norm $||\cdot||^2$, i.e. the composition, is convex. There are no specific conditions that you need to impose.